# How find follow script loading timeline in Chrome Dev tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I have a script on my website that is loading somewhere in the process. It has started behaving erroneously and I need to intercept where it's being loaded from. I developed the site some years ago and have forgotten all the intricacies involved. Is there a way in Chrome dev tools to see a timeline or tree of dependencies/loaded scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tab sources your can see all dependencies.

In tab network you can see time and order of they load.

Comment: Also, in Network check the "Initiator" column. If the origin point can be traced, this will link directly to what caused the item to be requested. Very useful when trying to trace things back.